# Invoke GitLab CI jobs from inside other jobs

Tags: gitlab-ci, jobs

I have many different GitLab CI jobs in my repository and dependent on variables that are set by an user in a config file I want to execute different sequences of jobs. My approach is to create a scheduler job that analyzes the config file and executes the jobs accordingly. However, I cannot figure out how to execute another job from within a job.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried? Based on what you are saying, you may want to trigger stages conditionally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a good use case for [dynamic child pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/parent_child_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines). This is pretty much the only way to customize a pipeline based on the outcome of another job.

From the docs:

```yaml
generate-config:
  stage: build
  script: generate-ci-config > generated-config.yml
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - generated-config.yml

child-pipeline:
  stage: test
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: generated-config.yml
        job: generate-config
```

In your case, the script `generate-ci-config` would be the analysis of your config files and creates a job configuration conditionally based on the config contents.